# Align an image where the source is set by javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I'm putting the network solutions 'seal' image on my site and they give you a javascript that sets the image. I'm wanting the image to align>right. However, if you want the image, they give you a javascript code stub and it handles the rest, which has no alignment property. I've even tried putting the javascript into a table that aligns right but apparently the javascript is rendered after the table is rendered by the browser.

Thoughts on how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the JavaScript code area with a div and give it a class or id. Then you can most likely target it with CSS.

```
<div id="network-solutions">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</div>


#network-solutions img {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Might want to do a span, the div is a block element